# TableViewController Vs UIViewController and a tableView inside

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode4.3

I have a Master/Details Application.
By default, we have the MasterViewController attached to a TableViewController, in addition, i have attached it to an Sqlite database and all the data are showing correctly as they should. So i added a UISearchBar, in order to search upon all the items ; 
 Search functionality's were working fine but the only bug was, the search bar disappears when scrolling down.
 So as a solution, i removed the TableViewController and created a simple UIVIewController and added a TableView , TableViewCell and a search bar in order to keep the search bar fix on top of the View as suggested by many people.
Now the difference between those two concepts is, the TableViewController (First Case) loads the whole data in the cells once the application loads, when the ViewController ( Second Case , with a tableView , tableViewCell and a searchBar) does not load anything at startup, It loads the different elements when the user start writing a word in the searchBar. How can i force the tableView to load all Elements at startup, just like if you have a TableViewCOntroller?
This is my code :

```
//
//  MasterViewController.m

#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "Author.h"
@interface MasterViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
NSString *authorNAme , *authorNAme2;

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize searchWasActive;
@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize theauthors;
NSString *PathDB;


-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{

    return YES;


}
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad


{ 
   // [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];


    //[self tableView:tableView willDisplayCell:[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"] forRowAtIndexPath:0]; 
    //[self.tableView 

    searchBar.delegate = (id)self;
   // [self.tableView reloadData];

   // [self configureCell:@"Cell" atIndexPath:0];
    [self authorList];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{


    [self setTableView:nil];
    tableView = nil;
    searchBar = nil;
    [self setSearchWasActive:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}




- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //[self authorList];
    // [filteredTableData release];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Cancel Button Clicked");

    // Scroll to top
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text =@" ";
}


- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)sender
{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;

}


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{ 
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;

    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Author* author in theauthors)

        {  //[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELECT * from books where title LIKE %@", searchBar.text];

            NSRange nameRange = [author.name rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch];
            NSRange descriptionRange = [author.genre rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch];
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredTableData addObject:author];
                NSLog(@"Item Added is %@" , author.name);

            }
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}





#pragma mark - Table View methods

-(NSMutableArray *) authorList{
    [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
    theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000000];
    // NSMutableArray * new2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithCapacity:100000];
    // authorNAme = theauthors.sortedArrayHint.description;
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSLog(@"Before the dbpath variable");
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dictionary_native.sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"After the dbpath variable");
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)

        {
            NSLog(@"1");
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        NSLog(@"Database correctly located");
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"2");
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }
        NSLog(@"Database correctly opened");

        // const char *sql = "SELECT F_Keyword FROM wordss";  
        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM wordss";

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                //   NSLog(@"entered the while statement");
                Author * author = [[Author alloc] init];

//                //  NSLog(@"Author initialised");
//                
                author.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
              //  NSLog(@"this is the author.name %@" , author.name);
                author.genre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)];
//                
              //  authorNAme=author.genre;              
//                

                [theauthors addObject:author];




            }
            //      authorNAme = author.genre;


        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        //   sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);.
        //   authorNAme = nil;

        //   authorNAme = Nil;
        return theauthors;
    }


}





- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

   // return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
//    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    int rowCount;
    if(self->isFiltered)
        rowCount = filteredTableData.count;
    else
        rowCount = theauthors.count;
    NSLog(@"This is the number of rows accepted %i" , rowCount);
    return rowCount;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    int rowCount = indexPath.row;

    Author *author = [self.theauthors objectAtIndex:rowCount];


    if(isFiltered){
        author = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        

    }
    else{
        author = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = author.name;


    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;


   // DetailViewController* vc ;
    MasterViewController *author;
    NSLog(@"This is the showDetailsForIndexPath");
    [self->searchBar resignFirstResponder];
   // Details* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
   // AuthorVC* author;

    if(isFiltered)
    {
        author = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        author = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //vc.author = author;
    authorNAme =  author.genre;
    authorNAme2 = author.name ;


   // author = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"This is the author.genre %@" , author.genre);

    //vc.author.genre = author.genre;
    authorNAme =  author.genre;
    authorNAme2 = author.name;

    //NSLog(@"This is the details %@",vc.author.genre);
    NSLog(@"This is the authorNAme Variable %@" , authorNAme);

    self.detailViewController.detailItem = authorNAme;
    self.detailViewController.detailItem2 = authorNAme2;

}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
  //  UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*
// Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
 */

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




//    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}

@end
```

Any help Will be highly appreciated...Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Did you check if the Delegate and Datasource methods are calling ie) numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I am a newb that's why i may be asking silly questions but i appreciate it if you try to help out

Comment: Put NSLogs inside those methods. NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection starts") and NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath starts")

Comment: They are not called on startup, only when the user type's in the search bar...how can i force them to be called at startup?

Comment: Try adding "[tableViewList reloadData];" in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I tried but its the same thing :S what can i do ?

Comment: Oh! I am not sure about the exact problem, but NSLog the tableview itself, to check if it is really existing. And NSLog the tableview.delegate and datasource, like NSLog(@"delegate - %@", self.tableview.delegate);NSLog(@"datasource - %@", self.tableview.datasource);

Comment: i get NULL :S...What can i do ?

Comment: If the tableview is in xib link it to correct object and set delegate and datasource.

Comment: Thank youuuu it worked!!!! paste it as an answer so i could up vote it and mark it correct for future users :d

Comment: Sure, posted answer, Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tableview is in xib link it to correct object and set delegate and datasource.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution :D